# Fibonacci memoization algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I'm struggling a bit with dynamic programming. To be more specific, implementing an algorithm for finding Fibonacci numbers of n.

I have a naive algorithm that works:

```
int fib(int n) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return n;
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

But when i try to do it with memoization the function always returns 0:

```
int fib_mem(int n) {
    if(lookup_table[n] == NIL) {
        if(n <= 1)
            lookup_table[n] = n;
        else
            lookup_table[n] = fib_mem(n-1) + fib_mem(n-2);
    }
    return lookup_table[n];
}
```

I've defined the lookup_table and initially stored NIL in all elements.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Here's the whole program as requested:

```
#include <iostream>

#define NIL -1
#define MAX 100

long int lookup_table[MAX];

using namespace std;

int fib(int n);
int fib_mem(int n);

void initialize() {
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        lookup_table[i] == NIL;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    long int fibonnaci, fibonacci_mem;
    cin >> n;

    // naive solution
    fibonnaci = fib(n);

    // memoized solution
    initialize();
    fibonacci_mem = fib_mem(n);

    cout << fibonnaci << endl << fibonacci_mem << endl;

    return 0;
}

int fib(int n) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return n;
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

int fib_mem(int n) {
    if(lookup_table[n] == NIL) {
        if(n <= 1)
            lookup_table[n] = n;
        else
            lookup_table[n] = fib_mem(n-1) + fib_mem(n-2);
    }
    return lookup_table[n];
}
```

Comment: This part of code looks ok. Could you please share the initialization code of `lookup_table`, definition of `NIL` and how you call this `fib_mem`?

Comment: lookup_table is not defined.

Comment: What's NIL defined as?

Comment: Chances are this is an out-of-bounds read, but we need the whole program.

Comment: Post the entire program.

Comment: You have used `==` in initialise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#define N 100

using namespace std;

const int NIL = -1;
int lookup_table[N];

void init()
{
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        lookup_table[i] = NIL;
}
int fib_mem(int n) {
    if(lookup_table[n] == NIL) {
        if(n <= 1)
            lookup_table[n] = n;
        else
            lookup_table[n] = fib_mem(n-1) + fib_mem(n-2);
    }
    return lookup_table[n];
}
int main()
{
    init();
    cout<<fib_mem(5);
    cout<<fib_mem(7);
}
```

Using the exactly same function, and this is working fine.

You have done something wrong in initialisation of `lookup_table`.

Comment: You have no idea if it's exactly the same function. You assumed declarations for `lookup_table` and `NIL` which may not hold.

Comment: IEW, `#define NIL 0`. There really is no good reason for that. If you need a named constant, `const int NIL = 0;` is typesafe. Also, your check for `n<=1` is non-performant. It would be much easier to just initialize the table to `{1,1,0, }`. But what is plain wrong is the missing check for `n<10` before reading the table.

Comment: @MSalters I agree with your point here. Will edit and explain properly. My point was to make minimum changes in his code. So, that this is understandable.

Comment: I used #define NIL -1

Comment: I've used this as initialization for lookup_table: void initialize() {
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        lookup_table[i] == NIL;
    }
} and then called initialize(); in main function before calling the fib_mem function.

Comment: You were right... The problem was in the initialization using the wrong operator. Beginners mistake I guess...

Comment: @PeterFaarup Next time, use `std::fill(lookup_table, lookup_table + MAX, NIL);` instead of a loop.

Answer (score 6):

I always advise to implement recursive memoization with this trick:

> Divide the recursive implementation of the memoization implementation, and make them call each others.

This tend to produce easy-to-write & easy-to-read code:

```
int fib_mem(int n);
int fib(int n) { return n <= 1 ? n : fib_mem(n-1) + fib_mem(n-2); }

int fib_mem(int n)
{
    if (lookup_table[n] == NIL) {
        lookup_table[n] = fib(n);
    }
    return lookup_table[n];
}
```

---

This allows to define a generic `memoize` template function to use with all your heavy functions:

```
template<auto&& func, class Key>
auto memoize(Key&& key)
{
    using Value = decltype(func(std::declval<Key>()));
    static std::map<Key, Value> lookup_table;
    if (lookup_table.find(key) == end(lookup_table)) {
        lookup_table[key] = func(key);
    }
    return lookup_table[key];
}

int fib(int n) { return n <= 1 ? n : memoize<fib>(n-1) + memoize<fib>(n-2); }
double fact(int n) { return n <= 0 ? 1 : n * memoize<fact>(n-1); }
```

[Full demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8YdT6j1K1)

Obviously, in non-sparse situation (if you expect to need almost all values of your function in a range, an array of optional could be a better choice than a map.

Comment: Nice use of std::optional. We all need to get more used to it. Got any benchmarks vs the old norm of "sentinel value" code? (I want to complain about std::array, because nobody mentioned an upper boundary, but ... okay now the question has been edited with an upper boundary. Nevermind.)

Comment: Is anyone concerned that for memoization in C++ the order of evaluation is unspecified? So it's not necessarily the case that `fib_mem(n-1) + fib_mem(n-2)` will first traverse the left hand side before the right. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: True, it must be addressed when the order matters. Here it does not, but in the general case it will.

Answer (score 2):

Since the issue is initialization, the C++ standard library allows you to initialize sequences without having to write `for` loops and thus will prevent you from making mistakes such as using `==` instead of `=`.

The [std::fill_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) function does this:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...

void initialize()
{
   std::fill_n(lookup_table, MAX, NIL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting concept. Speeding up by memoization.

There is a different concept. You could call it compile time memoization. But in reality it is a compile time pre calculation of all Fibonacci numbers that fit into a 64 bit value.

One important property of the Fibonacci series is that the values grow strongly exponential. So, all existing build in integer data types will overflow rather quick.

With [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet%27s_formula) you can calculate that the 93rd Fibonacci number is the last that will fit in a 64bit unsigned value.

And calculating 93 values during compilation is a really simple task.

We will first define the default approach for calculation a Fibonacci number as a `constexpr` function:

```
// Constexpr function to calculate the nth Fibonacci number
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    // Initialize first two even numbers 
    unsigned long long f1{ 0 }, f2{ 1 };

    // calculating Fibonacci value 
    while (index--) {
        // get next value of Fibonacci sequence 
        unsigned long long f3 = f2 + f1;
        // Move to next number
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
    }
    return f2;
}
```

With that, Fibonacci numbers can easily be calculated at runtime. Then, we fill a `std::array` with all Fibonacci numbers. We use also a `constexpr` and make it a template with a variadic parameter pack.

We use `std::integer_sequence` to create a Fibonacci number for indices 0,1,2,3,4,5, ....

That is straigtforward and not complicated:

```
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { getFibonacciNumber(ManyIndices)... } };
};
```

This function will be fed with an integer sequence 0,1,2,3,4,... and return a `std::array<unsigned long long, ...>` with the corresponding Fibonacci numbers.

We know that we can store maximum 93 values. And therefore we make a next function, that will call the above with the integer sequence 1,2,3,4,...,92,93, like so:

```
constexpr auto generateArray() noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}
```

And now, finally,

```
constexpr auto FIB = generateArray();
```

will give us a compile-time `std::array<unsigned long long, 93>` with the name FIB containing all Fibonacci numbers. And if we need the i'th Fibonacci number, then we can simply write `FIB[i]`. There will be no calculation at runtime.

I do not think that there is a faster way to calculate the n'th Fibonacci number.

Please see the complete program below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// All the following will be done during compile time

// Constexpr function to calculate the nth Fibonacci number
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) {
    // Initialize first two even numbers 
    unsigned long long f1{ 0 }, f2{ 1 };

    // calculating Fibonacci value 
    while (index--) {
        // get next value of Fibonacci sequence 
        unsigned long long f3 = f2 + f1;
        // Move to next number
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
    }
    return f2;
}
// We will automatically build an array of Fibonacci numberscompile time
// Generate a std::array with n elements 
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { getFibonacciNumber(ManyIndices)... } };
};

// Max index for Fibonaccis that for in an 64bit unsigned value (Binets formula)
constexpr size_t MaxIndexFor64BitValue = 93;

// Generate the required number of elements
constexpr auto generateArray()noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}

// This is an constexpr array of all Fibonacci numbers
constexpr auto FIB = generateArray();
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Test
int main() {

    // Print all possible Fibonacci numbers
    for (size_t i{}; i < MaxIndexFor64BitValue; ++i)

        std::cout << i << "\t--> " << FIB[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Developed and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2.

Additionally compiled and tested with clang11.0 and gcc10.2

Language: C++17

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in your `initialize()` function:

```
void initialize() {
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        lookup_table[i] == NIL; // <- mistake
    }
}
```

In the line pointed you compare `lookup_table[i]` and `NIL` (and don't use the result) instead of assigning `NIL` to `lookup_table[i]`.

For assignment, you should use `=` instead of `==`.

Also, in such situations the most right thing to do is compilation of your program with all warnings enabled. For example, MS VC++ shows the following warning:

```
warning C4553: '==': operator has no effect; did you intend '='?
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is on initialize function (you've used comparison operator '==' where you want a attribution operator '='). But, on semantics, you don't need initialize look_table with -1 (NIL) because Fibonacci results never will be 0 (zero); so, you can initialize it all with zero.
Look below the final solution:

```
#include <iostream>

#define NIL 0
#define MAX 1000

long int lookup_table[MAX] = {};

using namespace std;

long int fib(int n) {
    if(n <= 1)
        return n;
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

long int fib_mem(int n) {
    assert(n < MAX);
    if(lookup_table[n] == NIL) {
        if(n <= 1)
            lookup_table[n] = n;
        else
            lookup_table[n] = fib_mem(n-1) + fib_mem(n-2);
    }
    return lookup_table[n];
}

int main() {
    int n;
    long int fibonnaci, fibonacci_mem;
    cout << " n = "; cin >> n;

    // naive solution
    fibonnaci = fib(n);

    // memoized solution
    // initialize();
    fibonacci_mem = fib_mem(n);

    cout << fibonnaci << endl << fibonacci_mem << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, I am using a map instead of an array to store the memo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

map<int, unsigned long long> memo;

unsigned long long fibo(int n) {
    if (memo[n]) {
        return memo[n];
    }

    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    }
    memo[n] = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
    return memo[n];
}

int main() {
    int n; 
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Ans: " << fibo(n);
    return 0;
}
```