# Fibonacci series using looping and recursion

Tags: javascript

So, I have derived a code for Fibonacci series using Looping and Recursion technique. But, how can I write a code for the same without using looping and recursion technique?

This is using looping:

```
function fibouter()
 {
    let n=1;
     function fib()
    {
      let t1=0,t2=1,next,i;
       for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
       {
            next=t1+t2;
             t1=t2;
             t2=next;
        }
        n++;
       return t2;

     }
     return fib;
 }
   const run=fibouter();
```

This is using recursion :

```
function fib(n) 
{
   return n < 2 ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

How can I get the same output without using both looping and recursion ?
I wanted to try this out because it reduces the number of iterations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this can be easily found using Google

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't want to use a loop or recursion? Those are generally the ways that you implement the fibonacci sequence

Comment: @wmp224 i just wanted to try that out because the number of interations using looping and recursion is more.

Comment: Found using google: `function fib(n){ return Math.round(0.44721359549995682 * Math.pow(1.6180339887498949, n));}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Binet's Fibonacci Number Formula directly.

```js
function fib(n){return Math.round((Math.pow((1+Math.sqrt(5))/2,n)-Math.pow((1-Math.sqrt(5))/2,n))/Math.sqrt(5))}

for(let i = 0 ; i < 15; i++)
{
    console.log(fib(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though memoization is the best approach for fibonacci (Ref: [Fibonacci memoization algorithm in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457462/fibonacci-memoization-algorithm-in-c)) but as you are asking for a way to compute without recursion and loop, here is the most basic way. Though you will still require one loop, and what you can do is store pre-computed Fibonacci series in an array and print as required. Example:

```
int fib[100000];
fib[0] = 1;
fib[1] = 2;
for (int i=3; i<100000; ++i) {
    fib[i]=fib[i-1]+fib[i-2];
}
```

Then you can ask for which position of Fibonacci to be printed and simply print that index of the array fib[].

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just came up with a solution without looping and recursion.

```
function fib() {
    let t1=0,t2=1;
    return () =>  {
        const next=t1+t2;
        t1=t2;
        t2=next;

        return t1;
     }

    }
   let run=fib();
```

I think this solution is better and reduces recursion.